# Why is DateTime.Now off by 12 hours when using EF 4.3.1?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have a datetime2 column configured by EF 4.3.1 code first.  I just noticed that when I update my entity using DateTime.Now the value updated/inserted into SQL Server 2008 is off by 12 hours.

Any ideas where or why this is happening? The system time on my machine is correct and all of my stored procedures that I call directly and use GETDATE() work as expected.

Baffled.

One more thing to note.  The DateTime is correct all the way before context.savechanges is called.  Something EF is doing or the way EF is passing it to SQL Server is getting mixed up.

Comment: What timezone are you in? How does saving DateTime.UtcNow behave?

Comment: PST. Tried UtcNow as well with same incorrect behavior.

Comment: Well, you've got me baffled too, then...

Comment: It's probably something dumb on my part, but I just can't find it anywhere.

Comment: It was something dumb on my part.  I won't answer my own question but suffice to say the column was a 'LastActivityDate' type column that was being updated in 2 places based on different events and one of them was using UtcNow and the other just Now.  Dueling Banjos. Dohhh!

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx): GETDATE() Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value without the database time zone offset.

Most likely the cause of your problem is related to it.